# How PAT works in Azure

Tags: azure, networking, routes, nat

I am trying to understand [outbound connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#snat) in Azure, there was a specific point that is really confusing me,

> Multiple flows, each to a different destination IP address, port, and
>   protocol, share a single SNAT port

I'm unable to understand the above point, how can multiple flows different destination IP address, port, and protocol share a single SNAT port?

For eg,

Inside Local -> Inside Global -> Oustide Global

10.10.10.30 : 12345 -> 64.56.12.3: 5678 -> 1.2.3.4:80

10.10.10.40 : 11111 -> 64.56.12.3: 5678 -> 4.5.6.7:80

When there is a response back from 4.5.6.7:80 , how does Azure know to which internal IP it has to sent since they share the same port number?

Comment: Seems like a good question. You will get the best help if you ask this at Server Fault :)

Answer (score 1):

> how can multiple flows different destination IP address, port, and
>   protocol share a single SNAT port?

Per the [outbound connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#snat), **One SNAT port is consumed per flow to a single destination IP address, port.** This indicates that except the source information is rewritten from the virtual network private IP address, source port to public IP, SNAT port, every TCP flow mapping also considers the destination IP address and port changes when one SNAT port is consumed.

For multiple flows, each to **a different destination IP address**, port, and protocol, share a single SNAT port since there is a different destination IP address, the 5-tuple (the same source public IP, SNAT port, protocol, the **different destination IP address**, port) makes flows unique without the need for additional source ports to distinguish flows.

> When there is a response back from 4.5.6.7:80 , how does Azure know to
>   which internal IP it has to send since they share the same port
>   number?

In this scenario, when the response back from *4.5.6.7*, the destination server *4.5.6.7* does not know the internal IP *10.10.10.40:11111*  as they are *hidden* behind the VIP because of the SNAT. So the response sends to the VIP and SNAT port *64.56.12.3: 5678*. The system will translate the VIP and SNAT port to the source IP and source port according to the **each TCP flow mapping table (including the destination IP address and port)** *10.10.10.40:11111 -> 64.56.12.3:5678 -> 4.5.6.7:80*.

Comment: Besides TCP, NAPT also works for UDP and ICMP, but it breaks other transport protocols. It also causes problems for many application-layer protocols that use TCP or UDP.